# Use Google Calendar API to Access Specific Account's Calendar in Android

Tags: android, google-api, google-calendar-api

I was wondering if there was a way to access a specific calendar's data using the Google Calendar API in Android as opposed to the user's data. The app I am writing would have users add events/see if certain time slots were available on one calendar. So far I have not found any examples of how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

I got started with the 
[calendar sample app for Google API](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/calendar-android-sample/instructions.html?r=default) .
I hope it helps you.